# Error while launching the EC2 with Jenkins node

Tags: jenkins

[image][image][image]I am learning Jenkins and when I am trying to launch the EC2 via the Jenkins cloud node it shows an error. I have enabled port 8080 and not sure what I can do.
Amazon EC2 plugins are also downloaded.

[image: error-image]

Comment: Can you add the contents of your Jenkins config.xml along with the question??

Comment: Show the Cloud node details that configured on your Jenkins master. Also you can check the issue in Jenkins system logs with the `Logging ID`.

Comment: Yes i have added config.xml file and system logs screenshot as well please check once @Ajay

Comment: Try changing the `<useSecurity>true` to `<useSecurity>false` and comment out the `<authorizationStrategy>` and `<securityRealm>`. You can refer to this [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/Kn4VwdVB0fs?si=hNCMcowDQyQejcRx)

Comment: Yes i have tried this but this config.xml file is showing read only file I'm unable to configure it what should i do ? @Ajay